# Django model ORM Foreign key Relations

Tags: orm, django-models

I have three classes. I have accountid and I have to retrieve courtName and CaseName using Django ORM. Please help me to write a query.

### Model Classes

```
 class Court1(models.Model):
    CourtID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    CourtTypeID = models.IntegerField()
    CourtName = models.CharField(max_length=150)    
    class Meta:
       db_table = u'Court1'

 class CaseSummary1(models.Model):
   CaseID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   CaseName = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True, blank=True)
   DateFiled=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   class Meta:
     db_table = u'CaseSummary1'

  class PacerDocument1(models.Model):
   DocumentID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   PacerDocID = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   CourtID = models.ForeignKey(Court1)
   CaseID = models.ForeignKey(CaseSummary1)
   class Meta:
     db_table = u'PacerDocument1'



class DocumentAccess1(models.Model):
   AccountID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)    
   DocumentID = models.ForeignKey(PacerDocument1)    
   class Meta:
     db_table = u'DocumentAccess1'
```

### Sql Query

```
select CourtNAme,CaseName 
from documentaccess1 a,pacerdocument1 b,Court1 c,CaseSummary1 d  
where b.caseID_id  = d.CaseID 
  and b.CourtID_id = c.CourtID 
  and a.AccountID  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Django uses a clever way to do query: you just need to call a method like 
    courts = Court.objects.filter(case__id = ...)
If this is your first project in Django, you should read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/)